# How do I save JQuery UI sortable table positions to MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

i make an `php` web application for manage site products

i wanted to use `jquery sortable` for sorting the product position i use this method:

```
var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
    ui.children().each(function() {
        $(this).width($(this).width());
    });
    return ui;
};
$( "#sort tbody" ).sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight", axis: 'y', helper: fixHelper,
    update: function (event, ui) {
        var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

        // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/www/order.php'
        });
    }
});
$( "#sort tbody" ).disableSelection();
```

and in `order.php` i use this

```
<?php
include("db.php");

$i = 0;

foreach ($_POST['item'] as $value) {
    Execute statement:
          mysql_query(UPDATE cp_login SET [Position] = $i WHERE [EntityId] = $value);
    $i++;
}

include("db-close.php");
?>
```

this is not working what should i type in `[position]` section and `[EntityId]` section i could not understand please give me fixed code with explanation .

thank you

Comment: sir i wanted to save jquery sortable position to database but it is not working tell method to save

Comment: _"**Warning**
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used."_ In addition, I don't know what you have into `$_POST['item']` but your code inside the `foreach` is strange (`SET [Position]`, `Execute statement:`, missing quotes).

Comment: forget my code tell me your own method how to savwe jquery ui sortable in database

Comment: thank you for not helping my problem is solve